# How to fix SSRS Tablix column width?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm creating a report for MS Dynamics AX using SSRS. So far everything is working well, but this time i'm making a report consisting of many tablixes. Row height is fixed and there seem to be no issues from a horizontal perspective. Vertically however there is problem because columns are resizing randomly and my tablixes dont appear uniform. Everything appears perfect in design view but not in the output. Columns resize at run time. I have set the canGrow properties to false and resized all the columns manually but to no effect.
I've attached screenshots of my design and a small part of the preview/output.

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffrq4.jpg)

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Rcx.jpg)

Has anybody faced such an issue? Were they able to solve it?

Comment: Please check the following: 1) Do you have any padding in the cell. 2) There is a CanGrow property on the column and a CanGrow Property in the textbox for each cell. Make sure both are set to false.

Comment: 1) No padding at all
2) Both are set to false in all columns and cells
I dont know why but columns expand while the report rendering takes place

Comment: It is hard to tell because it seems that your screenshots are from different versions of your implementation. In the Design view your topmost row has three cells. In the Preview it only has one. Could you update your screenshots - and also include some pointers in the preview screenshot about where exactly your columns don't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed the cell to be 3.5 in, regardless of the data within it.  The fix wound up being to set the padding in the blank cell to that width.